# What is this green puffing smoke?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

Occasionally, after fighting certain enemies, my character will start emitting a puff of green smoke about once a second. After quite a while, it will finally stop. I have to assume this is some kind of detrimental status effect, but there is no obvious consequence of the smoke. What is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll notice that you have a little tiny icon next to your sharpness level.  This is the area for buffs and debuffs.  This particular one is a debuff, and it lowers your defense, as indicated by the black shield with a down arrow on it.  Most likely one of those tiny insects gave it to you; they like to do that.

To clear it out, a Nulberry should do the trick.  Or, you can wait until it goes away on it's own.

Comment: Armorskins and related items should work as well.